# Jquery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Estoy usando este plugin y me ha funcionado muy bien, pero necesito poder restar 2 fechas (inicio - fin) para mostrar el resultado en dias en un span. Como podria realizar esta operacion?posee este plugin algun metodo para realizar esto?.Esta es la manera con la que agrego las fechas.

```
$("#fechainicio").datepicker();
$("#fechafin").datepicker();
```

Comment: Entonces quieres restarle a fecha inicio la fecha fin y mostrar la fecha resultante? Explícate mejor !

Comment: tienes razon camilo disculpa, acabo de actualizar la pregunta, en ese span deberia mostrar los DIAS entre esas fechas. Gracias por la acotacion

Comment: las 2 fechas se almacenan en unos inputs, y la diferencia en dias de ellos se pondria en un span

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para calcular la cantidad de días que hay entre dos fechas yo haría lo siguiente:

```js
$("#fechaInicio").datepicker();
$("#fechaFin").datepicker(); 

$("#restar").click(function(){
    var fechaInicio = new Date($("#fechaInicio").val());
    var fechaFin = new Date($("#fechaFin").val());

    var diaEnMils = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    var resultado = (fechaFin.getTime() - fechaInicio.getTime()) / diaEnMils;

    console.log('Entre las dos fechas hay ' + resultado + ' días');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p>Fecha inicio: <input type="text" id="fechaInicio"></p>
<p>Fecha fin: <input type="text" id="fechaFin"></p>

<button id="restar">Restar fechas</button>
```

**EXPLICACIÓN:**

Básicamente estamos obteniendo la cantidad de milisegundos que hay en cada fecha, restamos los milisegundos y por último los convertimos a días.

Comment: estas onfire camilo, Solucionado

Answer (score 0):

yo uso esta funcion para sacar la diferencia en dias de 2 fechas dadas.

```
$("#restar").click(function(){
        var startDt=document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
        var endDt=document.getElementById("datepicker2").value;

        console.log(restaFechas(startDt,endDt));
    });




   function restaFechas(f1,f2){
   var aFecha1 = f1.split('/'); 
   var aFecha2 = f2.split('/'); 
   var fFecha1 = Date.UTC(aFecha1[2],aFecha1[1]-1,aFecha1[0]); 
   var fFecha2 = Date.UTC(aFecha2[2],aFecha2[1]-1,aFecha2[0]); 
   var dif = fFecha2 - fFecha1;
   var dias = Math.floor(dif / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
   return dias;
   }
```

Saludos.